# Do macOS time updates include leap seconds?

Tags: javascript, macos, date

I am curious if these leap seconds make their way to my computer in any way?

From the JavaScript [date object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date), I can see that they are not included in any way.  The base representation appears not to include them at all.

It appears they are added when the clock synches.  How does this effect JavaScript time?

Comment: it's good to refer to the Doc, right?  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMilliseconds

Comment: Do macOS time updates include leap seconds?

Comment: It appears they are added when the clock synches.  How does this effect JavaScript time?

Answer (score -2):

Following the comments below I adjusted the time strings in my "play around" snippet to GMT (with a "Z" at then end).

```js
console.log(new Date("2015-07-01T00:00:00Z")-new Date("2015-06-30T23:59:59Z"));
```

Comment: This code-only answer is very unclear. As far as I can tell the code is just expressing the second statement currently in the question - "From the JavaScript date object, I can see that they are not included in any way. The base representation appears not to include them at all.". Is there something that this answer says that isn't already expressed in the question?

Comment: If this is supposed to show a leap second in practice, the timestamps should be "2015-07-01T00:00:00Z" and "2015-06-30T23:59:59Z". However, since ECMAScript doesn't observe leap seconds, the result is 1000, which is exactly as expected and consistent with ECMA-262.

Comment: Hey everybody - please stay cool and don't kill me! :D This post was posted unintentionally by hitting the wrong button on my smartphone at some point. I was merely testing it for myself. In the code I used local German (MESZ) times which should show the leap second at least for me - _had_ it been observed by ECMA-262. Thanks for the further clarifying comments! I will delete this post again of course.